# Tag request for glue

Tags: feature-request

I've seen various glues mentioned.  There are quite a few different types of liquid bonding agents.  Perhaps glue as a tag for an article on super-glue rather than adhesives would be more intuitive for someone doing a search.  I can say that using adhesive when searching for something glue related is not intuitive.

Here's the super glue question.
[How should I store super glue to prevent it from drying out?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/4061/how-should-i-store-super-glue-to-prevent-it-from-drying-out)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this calls for a tag synonym:

[adhesive](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adhesive) ← [glue](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glue)

Many people will naturally type "glue" as a tag name. But *adhesive* is the broader term and should be the master tag, I think.

Comment: I have difficulty agreeing with the logic.  In technology, firewalls have the ability to route.  They have the name firewall in their own name (Cisco Firewall, Fortigate Firewall) yet classifying them as routers does not make sense because they are a firewall.

Comment: @pauldelasaux The logic doesn't apply in every case, otherwise we'd have very few tags. But in this case, I can't see a significant benefit in distinguishing between adhesive and glue. Would anyone be an expert in one but not the other? It also saves us from having to decide what is glue and what is adhesive.

Comment: gotcha, ty for the consideration.

Comment: What about all of the adhesives that don't have glue in their name. Epoxy, balsam (a resin) cocciona, library paste, methyl cellulose, starch, polystyrene cement, acrylonitrile, polyamide, polypropylene, rubber cement.  This was a comment on another question.  Would just like anyone's thoughts on this.  Most of the glue I use is some sort of polymer and doesn't have the word glue in it.  thanks for now and good luck.

Answer (score -1):

***I agree with you, but only products that have glue in the title or are widely recognized as "glue" should be in that tag. Because glue and adhesive are so closely related, this could call for a tag synonym later if not properly explained, I think that we would have to define what are glue questions and what are adhesive questions.***

Glue- Has glue in the title and could be classified as a adhesive. Glue could also be thicker, but this is not a rule.

Adhesive- For the other glue like products that are a adhesive, but not titled as a glue.

---

These definitions  may need some more tweaking, but I think that we cannot just name certain products as Glue, just because we want to. I think that a criteria of glue would have to be that they are already titled glue.